# Asus RT N16 router. Prevent redirection when there is no internet connection

Tags: router, internet-connection, modem

I am using Asus RT N16 wireless router connected to a PPPoE modem. When I web page is requested and there is no internet connection, the page gets automatically redirected to

http://www.asusnetwork.net/error_page.htm?flag=2

or their internet connection configuration page. This is a big issue if I open a browser with a saved session and there is no internet connection. All my pages redirect to the above page. Is it possible to disable this feature?

Comment: You're being redirected to a very spammy domain there, which isn't even owned by Asus. Something really funny is going on at your local network.

Comment: WHen there is no internet asusnetwork.net is like routerlogin.net for NetGear. It shows the router configuration page. When it is connected to internet, it shows a parked domain.

Comment: Wow, remind me never to use the vendor-provided firmware on an ASUS router, then.

Comment: My initial plan was to load Tomato firmware. But I'm afraid I will brick the router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to the Administration menu and open the System tab.
2. Enable the telnet server by setting “Enable Telnet” to “Yes”. Click Apply, wait for the changes to complete, then telnet to your router’s IP address and log in with the same username and password you use for the web interface.
3. At the command prompt, type: `nvram set web_redirect=0`
4. Changes should take effect immediately. This seems to prevent it, except for certain situations you probably won't run into, like when where the WAN connection is unconfigured.
5. Disable the telnet server again when done (if you don't need it).

(From here, which also includes further detail: https://moeffju.net/blog/disable-asus-rt-n66u-error-redirect. After reading the linked source code I'm even more inclined to run something like DD-WRT on my RT-AC68U!)

Comment: Thanks, I am currently running TomatoUSB (Shibby). I hope someone else will find this useful.

Comment: For newer models/firmwares (I have an RT-N66U), it's now a UI option under `Administration > System > Enable WAN down browser redirect notice`.

Answer (score 0):

For Asus RT-AC66U with Firmware Version:`3.0.0.4.382_52287` there is another solution without using telnet. Log in to the router, go to the Administration menu and open the System tab. Under Basic Config there is a setting to `Enable WAN down browser redirect notice`. Set this to no and there is no redirect.

[image]